# Visual studio 2010 file load error. Some bytes have been replaced with the unicode substitution character while loading file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

C:..\x.cs with Unicode (UTF-8) encoding. Saving the file will not preserve the original file contents.

-When I open the project, it takes over the .cs files and gives the above error.

-In the parts of the code written with Turkish letters, a question mark is shown instead of the Turkish letters ı,ü..etc. messages, method names... etc.

private void ABC��rToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

-I can't compile and run the project due to encoding error.

-Could this have something to do with visual studio version, operating system, TFS compatibility?
Does anyone know the solution to the problem?

Versions of the programs I use.
-Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
-Microsoft .Net Framework Version 4.8.09037 SP1Rel
-Windows 10 Pro 22H2

i grateful for your help.

Comment: `Saving the file will not preserve the original file contents` if you actually used UTF8, the content is preserved. If you see `��` it means the file was treated as ASCII using the wrong codepage. If that was meant to be a single character, the file was read as ASCII. Why are you using Visual Studio 2010 at all though? It's 13 years old, completely out of support and faced several localization (not Unicode) issues. A text formatting plugin caused problems in Turkish locales because its *American* developers didn't expect that changing the case of `i` would change the letter itself.

Comment: `Microsoft .Net Framework Version 4.8.09037` VS 2010 never supported .NET 4.5 or later. If you use VS 2010 to work with .NET 4.8 you'll run into far more serious issues sooner or later

Comment: Thanks for your help.
“So why are you using Visual Studio 2010?”
A project written in vs2010 and never upgraded to higher vs versions.
All dlls such as devexpress used in the project are old versions and the entire project needs to be examined and tested for upgrade compatibility, which is a very difficult task. To upgrade from vs2010 to higher versions, it is necessary to review Microsoft Visual Studio upgrade guides and tools.
If there is no other option, it can be done eventually.

Comment: "A text formatting plugin caused problems in Turkish locales"
Microsoft .Net Framework Version 4.8.09037 VS 2010 never supported ".NET 4.5 or later. If you use VS 2010 to work with .NET 4.8 you'll run into far more serious issues sooner or later"

Comment: It's been 13 years. `eventually` was a long time ago. Delaying only makes things harder and costlier, while increasing the company's liability - if you use discontinued runtimes and libraries, you're fully responsible for all problems, including security problems.

Comment: You are right in what you wrote. Since I cannot find another solution for the reasons I wrote above, I will reinstall the operating system and programs and try. Because my teammates run vs2010 on their other computers with win10 operating system without this coding error. I don't know how long I'll be able to work properly afterward and what other errors I'll get. :(

Comment: I know about the excuses (that's what these are) used by small companies (eg in the accounting sector) or indifferent managers in banks etc in certain Balkan countries. They're (or were) the same in Greece. The problem is the excuses often result in the company's demise, either because 1) the cost of supporting obsolete software doesn't allow the company to add any new features 2) the business landscape changes, eg with TLS1.2+ now a requirement, Docker deployment a must and multi-core the primary way of scaling or 3) they can't hire developers because nobody wants to work on obsolete software